# How to use rails gem to connect to API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to connect my RoR app to the api at this website https://www.humanapi.co

There is a gem available here, https://github.com/humanapi/humanapi, that is supposed to make the process easy. I have read through the documentation several times Unfortunately, because I am new to RoR and web development in general, I'm not exactly sure how to implement this. Any help you can give is greatly appreciated!

Specifically: It says to configure the initilizer using these values..

```
HumanApi.config do |c|
c.app_id = ENV['HUMANAPI_KEY']
c.query_key = ENV['HUMANAPI_SECRET']
end
```

I understand this in concept, i have used omniauth etc before. But do I need to create another initializer or just use an existing one?

and finally, this is what i don't understand the most...

```
  humanizable :get_the_token

def get_the_token
    # the code to reach the token
```

"# the code to reach the token

I'm at a complete loss with that, how would i get the token? here is the documentation for web access to the api (which i've read a lot) http://hub.humanapi.co/docs/connect-web-guide

Comment: what didn't you understand ncrouch25 ?

Comment: I edited the original post

Comment: hmmmm maybe you can contact andreimpop(the developer of the gem)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not your fault, the documentation of the gem is poorly written and doesn't show what exactly is going on or what is it even doing

This gem is also outdated, created 3 years ago and there are no issues or updates or anything. you better go looking for a different gem that do the functionality you want

Comment: Yeah I thought of that, unfortunately there are no other gems that function, (there is an omniauth gem, but the api has deprecated use of it,) and considering that this gem is made by the actual company i would hope that it still works. But yes, the documentation is poorly written